# vim python-mode vertical windows

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I'm using vim with the python-mode plugin.  All windows (runtime, documentation, Error, etc) opened by python-mode split the window horizontally.  How can I change the default behavior to split vertically?

Comment: added the following to .vimrc  `autocmd BufEnter {__run__,__doc__} :wincmd L`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear that python-mode provides an option that allows you to control the direction of its splits.  However, you can create an autocommand which will automatically move the window to the right side when it opens.

```
autocmd BufEnter {window_name_list} :wincmd L
```

So for python-mode, the command should look like this:

```
autocmd BufEnter __run__,__doc__ :wincmd L
```

**NOTE**

This autocommand will move the window to the very right of the screen.
You can replace `L` with `H` if you want it to split to the left instead of the right.

If you need help on autocommands and wincmd, read these help topics:

```
:help :autocmd
:help autocmd-events
:help :wincmd
:help CTRL-W
```

Comment: Thanks this works great.  I added the following to .vimrc.  
`autocmd BufEnter {__run__,__doc__} :wincmd L`

Comment: That's good, but the brackets aren't necessary.  Just  `autocmd BufEnter __run__,__doc__ :wincmd L` will work just fine.